# Characterization of density and adherence in topological space.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, dense-subspaces

I would like to show the following theorem !

Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological space and $A$ a subset of the latter. Then

- A point $x$ is in $\bar{A}$ if and only if every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$.
- The set $A$ is dense in $X$ if and only if $A$ intersects any non empty open set of $X$.

My attempt :

- For the "only if" part we suppose that $x$ is not in $\bar{A}$, it means that $x\in X\setminus\bar{A}$ and we have found a neighborhood of $x$ (namely the open set $X\setminus\bar{A}$) which does not intersect $A$ since $A\subset\bar{A}$. For the "if" part we suppose that $V$ is an open set which contains $x$ and that does not intersect $A$, we conclude by the fact that $\bar{A}\subset X\setminus V$ since the complementary set of $V$ is a closed set in $X$ and this closed set must contain $\bar{A}$ which is the smallest closed set containing $A$.
- For the "if" part, we have that $A$ is dense in $X$ which means that $\bar{A} = X$. By the first part of the theorem we know that any neighborhood of all points (that is any non empty set) in $\bar{A} = X$ intersects $A$. For the "only if" part, we know that $A$ intersects any non empty set of $X$, consider $x\in X$, every neighborhood of $x$ (which is a non empty set of $X$) intersects $A$, which implies that $x\in\bar{A}$.

Insight of the attempt :

- A neighborhood of $x$ can be simply an open set containing $x$.
- A non empty set in a topological space can always be identified to a neighborhood of a point in this space. **Not clear and probably false**

I would like to know if my intuition/understanding of these concepts seem correct and if my proof is coorect please ?

Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using "any non empty set" to mean "any non empty open set" but otherwise looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you refer to the argument using neighborhood of a point to consider a non empty set what I have in mind is that for every non empty set I can find a neighborhood of a point of this non empty set includes in : if the non empty set is open so I just have to consider this set but by writting this I see that I have no argument to the case of closed set, maybe I am wrong ?

Comment: Even in the theorem statement "every non empty set" should be "every non empty open set" (or perhaps "every set with non empty interior"). The only way $A$ can intersect every non empty set in $X$, including singletons $\{x\}$, is if $A = X$.

Comment: You are totally right. Thank you a lot !